# how to push only recent commits instead of pushing all commits to master from uat branch

Tags: php, git, bitbucket

i have a list of 60 commits in UAT branch and i want to push only specific commits to master.

`git branch cherry-branch origin/master
git checkout cherry-branch
git cherry-pick <#commit-hash>`

created new branch in my local and tried to do a cherry-pick with new branch, it throws a conflict.
could you please guide me to find a right way.

i tried below command also, not working
`git push origin <#commit hash>:cherry-branch`

Thanks

Comment: The verb *push* has a specific technical meaning in Git, and you can't do that. The cherry-pick approach is *probably* the right idea but you'll need to learn to resolve merge conflicts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can checkout master:

```
git checkout master
```

And then apply the commits from your UAT branch to master with `git cherry-pick`

```
git cherry-pick <commit id from uat branch>
```

Then push your changes back to master

```
git push
```

Note, that you will have to probably apply the changes to master in the same order that they were applied to the UAT branch. So, start with the oldest commit, and work from there.